# subquery or passthrough; SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access, subquery

I have an Access 2000 query that works on linked tables from SQL Server 2008 R2. I need to write it as a view or pass through query:

`

```
SELECT Max(CLng((Mid([tbl1]![ID],5)))) AS lastnumberused
FROM [tbl1]
WHERE ((([tbl1]![ID]) Like "OODD*" And ([tbl1]![ID]) Not Like "OODDid*" And ([tbl1]![ID]) Not Like "*x") AND ((CLng((Mid([tbl1]![ID],5))))<1000000));
```

`

So what I'm looking for is the max number under 1000000 that begins with OODD% but not OODDID%. Also the record cannot end with 'x'.

My code in TSQL for SQL Server looks like this and doesn't work...

`

```
SELECT    
convert (int, (substring(tblMain.BarcodeID,5,10))) as X1, [ID]
FROM tblMain
WHERE ([tbl1]![ID] LIKE N'OODD%') 
AND ([tbl1]![ID] NOT LIKE N'%x%') 
AND ([tbl1]![ID] NOT LIKE N'OODDID%') 
Select MAX (x1)+1
from bar1
where (x1<1000000)
```

`

suggestions?
thanks,H

Update 15june2013

    `WITH T1 (number)
    AS
    (SELECT substring(tbl1.ID,5,10)
    FROM tblMain AS tbl1
    WHERE (ID LIKE N'oodd%')
    AND  (ID NOT LIKE N'%x%')
    AND  (ID NOT LIKE N'ooddID%')) 
    SELECT (cast((number)as int)) FROM T1`

This works and returns 561770 rows.

`With T1(number)
as(SELECT     cast(SUBSTRING(ID, 5, 7)as int)
FROM         tblMain as tbl1
WHERE     (tbl1.ID LIKE N'oodd%') 
AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%x%') 
AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%ooddID%')
AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(tbl1.ID,5,10))=1)
Select max(number) from T1`

Also works but returns a number above 1000000

When a where statement is added the following code includes records that should have been excluded in the previous statement. 

`With T1(number)
as(SELECT     cast(SUBSTRING(ID, 5, 7)as int)
FROM         tblMain as tbl1
WHERE     (tbl1.ID LIKE N'oodd%') 
AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%x%') 
AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%ooddID%')
AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(tbl1.ID,5,10))=1)
Select max(number) from T1
where x1 <1000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE clause contains a [tbl1] table which is not present in the FROM clause. You should either change it to tblMainBee or add an "tbl1" alias in the FROM clause with AS.

Also, you have two unconnected SELECT statements, instead of a single one. Again, in the second SELECT, there is a bar1 table which doesn't appear anywhere else... is it correct?

Another error is that you cannot use "!" to separate table name and field name. You must use a dot.

Finally, there are issues when trying to convert the data type. You don't need it since comparison between strings also works.

Your access SELECT statement is much more straightforward.

Try with

```
WITH T1(number) AS (

SELECT substring(tbl1.ID,5,LEN(tbl1.ID)-4)
FROM tblMainBee as tbl1
WHERE ([tbl1].[ID] LIKE N'OODD%')
  AND ([tbl1].[ID] NOT LIKE N'%x%')
  AND ([tbl1].[ID] NOT LIKE N'OODDID%')
  AND (IsNumeric(substring(tbl1.ID,5,LEN(tbl1.ID)-4)) = 1)
) 
SELECT max(convert(bigint,number)) FROM T1 WHERE number < 1000000;
```

The second type conversion is implicit since 1000000 is numeric. The first one is necessary. Otherwise, it would consider '12346' bigger than '123421'.

Comparison between strings only works if they have fixed length.

Regards,

Comment: Clon- THANK YOU. This code is running and you were correct in spotting a mistake I made in the original post. I was trying to hide table and field names. While this works without error, it is still not giving the correct answer that my Access front end is giving. THanks again - I will post the working code at a later date/

Comment: Hikerd- Could you show me the answer you get vs. the correct one? Also, is there any consistent structure in the ID field's content? It could be of some help.

Comment: Also, you should change the parameters of the substring function (5 and 10) to meet your requirements. I've had to guess them based on the given information.

Comment: Clon- Access is returning "861160" while

Comment: `SELECT cast(SUBSTRING(ID, 5, 10)as int )
 FROM tblMain as tbl1 
 WHERE (tbl1.ID LIKE N'oodd%') 
 AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%x%') 
 AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%oodID%')
  AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(tbl1.ID,5,10))=1` returns 567039 rows of int's as expected.

Comment: `With T1(number) 
as(
SELECT cast(SUBSTRING(ID, 5, 10)as int )
 FROM tblMain as tbl1 
 WHERE (tbl1.ID LIKE N'oodd%') 
 AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%x%') 
 AND (tbl1.ID NOT LIKE N'%ooddID%')
  AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(tbl1.ID,5,10))=1
  ) 
  Select max(number) from T1 ID` returns 8470102 (as expected) but faults when `where number <1000000` or `where number <'0001000000'` is added to the end. "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ant103439' to data type int".

Comment: Well, clearly there are non-numeric characters in the beginning of the substring, so the initial position shouldn't be 5 but 8. Can you show the structure of your ID field? Something like xxxxyyyyy0000000000zzz. What you're interested in is the numerical part of your code. More precisely, you want to know the initial position and the length of that part. You have to use them as parameters for the substring function. All of it changes if your ID doesn't have a defined structure.

Comment: Also, in the final condition (WHERE number < '0001000000') the length of the string must be consistent with the substring function's second parameter. Ex: substring(tbl1.ID, 5, 8) --> number < '00100000'. Do you understand? The code isn't completely finished, since only you know the right values to use.

Comment: I was considering that the structure of your ID field was fixed. Considering your examples more closely, I realize that this assumption was wrong. Hence, I've changed the code again. Please, check it, first without changes.

Comment: This works and thanks for all the help. And yes the ID field changes as we incorporate other institution's ID numbers/nvarchar into our dataset. It works - and I should just stop here but... Thanks for sifting through a poor worded question and data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ID,5,9) as INT))+1
from tblMainBee
where
    ID Like 'OODD%'
    AND ID Not Like 'OODDid%'
    AND ID Not Like '%x'
    AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(ID,5,9))=1
    AND CAST(SUBSTRING(ID,5,9) as INT)<1000000
```

Comment: Alexander. Thanks for the code. This is still returning a previous error. "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '188540x' to data type int.". I'm currently working on mods Clon's answer.

Comment: +1 because of the ISNUMERIC function. I'd only change SUBSTRING(ID,5,9) with SUBSTRING(ID,5,LEN(ID)-4) for more safety.